# Accessing Data Resources for Python Poetry Based Packages

Tags: python-packaging, python-poetry, python-install

I recently started experimenting with Poetry for package and dependency management, and I am still getting used to the differences between it and my experience with setuptools.  Specifically, I would appreciate help in understanding how to handle the following scenario.

I have a data file that I want to bundle with my package stored in a package subdirectory.  Using setup.py I would specify the file and directory names in the setup.py file and then access the file in my code using the pkg_resources API.

What is the equivalent approach using Poetry and pyproject.toml?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike `setuptools` `poetry` bundles automatically all files within your package folder into your package, unless you haven't explicit excluded them in your `.gitignore` or the `pyproject.toml`.

So after the package is installed, you can access them with `pkg_resources`.

Comment: `pkg_resources` is deprecated, is it possible to use `importlib.resources` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could still use *setuptools*'s `pkg_resources`.

You could also use one of those from Python's own standard library:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.resources.read_binary

Answer (score 0):

sinoroc's answer is deprecated. The new method since `python 3.9` is:

```py
p = importlib.resources.as_file(importlib.resources.files('resources') / 'resource.toml')
with p as f:
    my_toml = tomllib.load(f.open('rb'))    # as an example
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't really answer the original post. I don't have a solution for poetry yet.